# Is it possible to completely hide a tooltip using pointFormatter?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the code below I have a pointFormatterfor a tooltip. What I'd like to do is to, for some points, completely hide the tooltip. I have tried returning null or false in these cases, however, an empty tooltip still appears. Is it possible to completely hide a tooltip when using pointFormatter? I've seen that with other formatters it is posisblet return null or false but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

```
            tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(37,37,37,0.95)",
                style: {
                    padding: 10
                },
                headerFormat: "",
                pointFormatter: function () {
                    if(this.hrr_num === 16){
                        return null;
                    }
                    return self.getToolTip(parseInt(this.hrr_num));
                },
                followPointer: false,
                shadow: false,
                shape: "square",
                hideDelay: 0
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several `*formatter` Functions in the Tooltip Object. The one you are looking for is just called `formatter`. If you return `false` in this function then the tooltip will not be displayed at all. This should do the trick:

```
        tooltip: {
            [...]
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.point.hr_num === 16) {
                    return false;
                }
                return self.getToolTip(parseInt(this.point.hr_num));
            },
            [...]
        }
```